# Not able to list dataproc jobs for certain clusters in google cloud

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

We have dataproc clusters.And I am trying to list the jobs in the cluster using a service account. I am able to list the jobs in a certain cluster but not on few others within the same project. No errors. But jobs are not showing up. I am using the code below. Please let me know for any thoughts.

```
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1 as dataproc
from google.cloud import bigquery
import google.cloud  as resources
from google.oauth2 import service_account as sa
from google.cloud.dataproc_v1 import JobControllerClient

client = Clients.get_client(ClientType.DATAPROC, name="x")
client_cluster =  Clients.get_client(ClientType.DATAPROC_CLUSTER, name="x")
clus_collec = []

try:
        cl_seq = client_cluster.list_clusters(project_id='y', 
                       region='us-central1')
        for k in cl_seq:
             clus_collec.append(k.cluster_name)

        for m in clus_collec:
            data = client.list_jobs(project_id='y', region='us-central1', filter=f"clusterName={m} AND labels.execution_date=2022-08-25")
            print(data)
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Can you add more details about the difference between the cluster which you can list jobs and the cluster which you cannot, especially from IAM perspective. And what role does the service account have?

Comment: Thanks. What I see is that the properties below are not enabled for other clusters. "dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable": "true",
"dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable": "true",